# JAVA, weird result of the loop

Tags: java

I have simple question. Why result of this loop is 12? I thought it will be 11...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 10;

    while (i++ <= 10){
    }

    System.out.println(i);
}


//RESULT: 12
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will run the conditions in the while-loop twice, first time when `i = 10,` then it will increment it to 11. Then it will check if `i <= 10` again, and it will be false, but it will still increment `i` resulting in it becoming 12.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because it must do another check before exiting the loop.

```
i is 10
check i++<=10?
i is 11
check i++<10?
exit
i is 12
```

Answer (score 1):

`i++` says "give me the current value of `i`, *then* increment it".  In this case, when `i = 10` it's incremented to `11` then the the expression is true for the previous value `10`, so the loop repeats, does the test for `i = 11`, increments `i` to `12`, and the expression is now false, stopping the loop.

This post-increment behavior is somewhat confusing and therefore should only be used when it's exactly what you need.  In general, it's much better to pretend `++` doesn't return anything, this will generally make the intent of your code much more clear:

```
while(i <= 10) {
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Iteration 1 : i=10
condition true  ===>>> while loop executed once
i incremented to 11


iteration 2 : i=11
condition false ===>>> while loop exited
but after exiting the while loop
i is incremented again to ===>>> i =12

and that is what you get as output
```